# Add table row on button click in php and set fields values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form where I have to add table rows on button click.

Here is the table row which I have to add dynamically: (addProdToGroup.php)

```
<tr style="text-align: center;" id="products">
  <td><?php $j ?></td>
  <td><select class="form-control" name="code" id="productID" style="width: 429px;">
    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product`";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<option id='".$row['code']."' value='".$row['code']."'>".$row['pname']."</option>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="hsnNo" id="hsnNo" readonly></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" readonly></td>
  <td class="coljoin"><input type="number" format="2" name="amount"></td>
  <td>
    <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is the table in which I have to add the above-mentioned rows: (order.php)

```
<table id="productTable" class="table-c">
                  <tr>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%;">SR No.</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 45%">DESCRIPTION</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">HSN/SAC</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">QTY IN-HAND</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">ENTER OUTWARD QTY</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%">Delete</th>
                  </tr>
                  <div class="dynamics">

                  </div>
                </table>
```

On clicking the button, an AJAX query is being called for the PHP code. The ajax code is: (order.php)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addOrderProduct').click(function(){
      var j = 1;
      var dataString = "j="+j;
      $.ajax({
        url: "addProdToOrder.php",
        type: "post",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(response){
          $('.dynamics').html(response);
        }
      });
    });
  })
</script>
```

The output should be like this: 
[Format for the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbXMT.png)

Also, I have a script to update the fields upon selecting the product from the drop-down. How to make that run for every row added into the form?
Here is the code for updating fields: (order.php)

```
$('#productID').change(function(){
      var code = $(this).val();
      console.log(code);
      var dataString = 'code='+code;

      $.ajax({
        url: "getProdDets.php",
        type: "post",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(response){
          var Vals = JSON.parse(response);
          console.log(Vals);
          $("input[name='hsnNo']").val(Vals.hsnNo);
          $("input[name='qty']").val(Vals.qty);
          console.log(Vals.hsnNo);
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service.
Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and explain the error you're facing.
Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Make the JS clone a table row and then add the clone into the table. No need to go back to PHP to do this

Comment: same question and same code i think its duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49293039/set-input-value-upon-select-option-in-php/49293262#49293262

Comment: @RahulShrivastava The mentioned post is mine using another account. I asked a different question using the same code.

Comment: How to insert field details from ajax query for every new row added?

Answer (score 1):

Change `div` to `tbody` in table and use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append) to add dynamic rows like,

HTML changes:

```
<table id="productTable" class="table-c">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%;">SR No.</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 45%">DESCRIPTION</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">HSN/SAC</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">QTY IN-HAND</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">ENTER OUTWARD QTY</th>
             <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%">Delete</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="dynamics"></tbody>
</table>
```

Change in `success`

```
....
success: function(response){
    $('.dynamics').append(response);
}
....
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to add multiple rows.